# Returns undefined as a listitem

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I get list items from a custom list it returns `undefined` on the top and after other list items.
How to fix this problem?

[image]

my code:

[image]

Comment: Well without your code it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong..

Comment: hi. I added code now

Comment: I guess the title of the 1st listitem is empty?

Comment: FYI, I see the getQueryStringParameter function (used in so many bloated examples). Microsoft gives you [JSRequest](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20820.sharepoint-2010-about-jsrequest.aspx) for free in SharePoint.

Comment: As for adding your code... paste your code in a texteditor.. indent all with one Tab (at least 4 spaces), then paste it in StackOverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to un-initialized variable `lstString` 
In `onS()` function, initialize the string variable by replacing `var lstString;` with `var lstString = ""`

Comment: Spot on, the `undefined` text is from the first time the variable is concated with `+=` when it is not yet "typed" as a string in javascript

Comment: +1 Nice catch :)